# Ajax parameter and rh-action

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please see the response of my ajax request below

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 11 Oct 2013 05:44:55 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
rh-action:rh/ignore
Server:BS-rapture/1.4.19
```

can someone tell what what the hell is this "rh-action" ? I tried to search this in google, but couldnt able to find a promising answer.

Thanks and regards,
Tismon Varghese

Comment: I found an answer on a German site on an eCommerce framework. According to [sinnerschrader.de](http://dev.sinnerschrader.de/CommerceWiki/index.php/Glossar:Request-Handling-Action_%28RH-Action%29) `rh-action` stands for Request-Handling-Action. The action required to add an item to a shopping trolley.

Answer (score 0):

> can someone tell what what the hell is this "rh-action" ?

This is not a standard HTTP header. It might be some proprietary stuff of the API you are using.